Main panel replacement without upgrade
Can I use 200amps main breaker panel with a 100 amps service? Not ready to upgrade service yet but need new main panel. Thanks

What make and model is your existing panel?

Big panels and smaller main breakers is okay.  Panels are usually up to rating/do not go over.
The why you need to change might be important.
Breakers are usually matched to panels/panels only take certain makes and models of breakers.
Unless you have one of the known bad panels, getting a new panel similar to the old one might save some cost of breakers.

Not directly. A 200A panel itself is OK, but you will need 100A protection to limit the current through the meter and the service drop. The main breaker will need to be replaced with a 100A (if even available), or removed and blanked off and back-fed through a 100A breaker in a load position.

If you need a new 100a panel then just buy a 100A for temporary use then throw it out when you do the service. A 100A breaker for a 200A panel is going to cost at least $80 just for the breaker. Buying a 100A panel panel that comes with a half dozen load breakers is $100.  You're not saving anything by  oversizing the panel now.
